# how can I get my extended partition to come back after I used gnome-disk to create an NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, grub2, gnome-disk-utility

I am just using gnome-disks in 18.04.4 (disk OK, 1 bad sector)

The following partitions existed on 250GB drive  from about 2014

1. windows recovery primary partition
2. windows OS primary partition
3. blank space 21Gb
4. extended partition
   a) b) c) ubuntu, ubuntu swap, ubuntu user home directory

Right now I have booted from ubuntu in the extended partition

Then I used disk partition to make the 21Gb blank space be a partition. It said 'Warning, you can only make 1 more primary partition'  so I figured OK and did it.  I attempted to make it an NTFS partition (maybe that was a blunder.)

And then, what happened was the extended partition went away in gnome-disk so now it thyinks i have Partition 3 0.0KB unknown, followed by free space 147GB.  I know that is not right.  I can access files on it now, but I think it likely will not mount right next time I boot up.

What tools can I use to understand this, and see the disk partition more clearly, and then return the disk to a good usable state?

P.S. also, then I deleted the new NTFS partition to see if my extended partition would come back, but it did not.

Edit: here's fdisk info for that drive:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x17b43163

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048  20482047  20480000   9.8G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb2        20482048 160255999 139773952  66.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       201676798 488396799 286720002 136.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       261677056 325675007  63997952  30.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       325677056 488396799 162719744  77.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       201676800 261677055  60000256  28.6G 83 Linux
```

In Gnome Disk the diagram appears with this info:

1. RECOVERY Partition 1 10 GB NTFS
2. OS Partition 2 72 GB NTFS   (it has a star)
3. Free Space 21GB
4. Partition 3 0.0 KB Unknown
5. Free Space 147GB

Comment: Please add output of  `sudo fdisk-l` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1250647/edit) to your question.

Comment: Looks like your extended partition is still alive. Try to use gparted to add the wanted partition in the unallocated space.

Comment: Did you restart the Gnome Disk application?